# If I crop an image in wordpress and revert the image back to the original size "thumbnail settings" disappears

Tags: php, css, image, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme that relies on using wordpress' image cropping functionality.

The problem I am facing is that when I crop an image, lets say I'm not happy with the crop, so I revert back to the original size, on the right hand side there should be a "thumbnail settings" box of the media admin panel.

It looks like this:

[image: thumbnail settings]

Now, as I said, after reverting back to the original image size this box is not there and I can no longer crop an image and choose the option of whether to apply it to thumbnails.

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Edit: The restore to Original Size option:

[image: Original Size]

Comment: how are you reverting back to the original size?

Comment: @otherDewi sorry I didn't include in the image, but above that box is an option, along with scale image to revert back to original image size.